# How can I reference a section in Grunt file to avoid redundancy?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

This might seem like a `grunt`'s `grunt-contrib-copy` specific question, but it actually applies to a more generic scope.

### Redundant configuration

I have the following `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
   
    copy: {
      examples: {
        cli: {
          files: [
            { src: ['src/client.js'], dest: 'examples/client.js' }
          ]
        },
        srv: {
          files: [
            { src: ['src/server.js'], dest: 'examples/server.js' }
          ]
        },
        all: { /* ATTENTION: Redundant part! */
          files: [
            { src: ['src/client.js'], dest: 'examples/client.js' },
            { src: ['src/server.js'], dest: 'examples/server.js' }
          ]
        }
      },
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [...]);
  grunt.registerTask('build-examples', ['copy:examples']);
};
```

But it is redundant!

### Attempting to avoid redundancy

I would like to do something like:

```
all: {
  files: examples.cli.files.concat(examples.srv.files)
}
```

But this is not possible.

What is the best practice here? Thanks

Comment: You can define variables in your gruntfile to get rid of redundancy, it's a regular .js file. (Also, take a look at grunt [options](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) and [templates](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) for related mechanisms)

Comment: You are writing JavaScript, not Grunt. That said, and coupled with every other person's contribution you should be my confident in what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember this is JavaScript code, so you can do anything you can do in JavaScript code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  var clientFiles = [
    { src: ['src/client.js'], dest: 'examples/client.js' }
  ];
  var serverFiles = [
    { src: ['src/server.js'], dest: 'examples/server.js' }
  ];
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    copy: {
      examples: {
        cli: {
          files: clientFiles
        },
        srv: {
          files: serverFiles
        },
        all: {
          files: clientFiles.concat(serverFiles)
        }
      },
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [...]);
  grunt.registerTask('build-examples', ['copy:examples']);
};
```